# Do the big balls of yarn have any advantages over small ones?

Tags: poochy-and-yoshis-woolly-world

I noticed that sometimes I get small balls of yarn that I can shoot and sometimes I get big ones, and there is a badge that allows me to just get big ones.

Is there a functional difference between the big balls and the small ones? Or is it just cosmetic?

Comment: Please stop editing this. Can we just leave it at the title where it includes the word yarn? I don't know why my title has gotten so contentious compared to other more humorous titles on the site, but I am tired of it constantly being edited. It's not worth it. Please leave the title as it is. I really just want an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bigger yarn balls can apply yarn to more objects before they expire. A small yarn ball will vanish when it hits an enemy or wireframe, while a bigger one will bounce off enemies and travel through wireframes, affecting everything it hits until it shrinks to small size and makes one more shot. This means you can also tongue a big yarn ball after it hits something and keep the rest for later.